# Rellenar entry con la selección de un combobox Python

Tags: mysql, python

Soy nueva en esto de la programación y estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación con base de datos.

He incluido un combobox con los datos numérico de una base de datos, y me gustaría que al seleccionar el numero 1, me de el registro.

Por ejemplo pulso el numero uno en el combobox y que me lo relacione con el nombre que tiene el numero uno.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes que mostrarnos que estas haciendo para que sepamos como ayudarte...

Comment: Dale una mirada a este enlace, Misma pregunta pero con solución. https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Python/1373159-Capturar-item-de-un-combobox.html